# Invalid seconds in timestamp field in SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

I've a timestamp field in a table where second values SUBSTR(col,13,2) are 60+ in some places.
I want to update invalid second portion of the timestamp field and convert this kind of data into valid timestamp format DDMMYYYYHHMISS.

Sample data:

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE TEST (COL VARCHAR(50)) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO TEST (04012022000010);
INSERT INTO TEST (31012022000066);
INSERT INTO TEST (02012021000067);

    COL
1   31012022000066
2   02012021000067
3   04012022000010
```

Comment: Show us the expected result as well.

Comment: Teradata has a proper timestamp data type. Why are you using varchar?

Comment: What's the expected result for `02012021000067`, `2021-01-02 00:0.:..`?

Comment: @dnoeth, jarlh 
I've couple of rows where incorrect seconds are coming. And from varchar table i am inserting data into datestamp column.

The expected output is seconds SUBSTR(col,13,2) + 40 where seconds are invalid in DDMMYYYYHHMISS format.       
31012022000106
02012021000107
04012022000010
        
I am ok with other suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's @Kendle's logic in Teradata SQL:

```
select 
   cast(substring(col from 1 for 12) as timestamp(0) format 'ddmmyyyyhhmi') +
   cast(substring(col from 13 for 2) as interval second) as TS_correct,
   to_char(TS_correct,'ddmmyyyyhhmiss')
from test;
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for. Thanks @dnoeth

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is what you are needing. We convert the string without the seconds to DATETIME and add the number of seconds.
I give 2 versions because the DATETIME format requested is not the standard ISO format
The first request uses the date format as requested in the question. I give 2 versions because I don't know whether your local settings modify the automatic functions.

```
DDMMYYYYHHMISS
```

```
SELECT CAST(
   CONCAT(
      SUBSTRING(COL,1,12),'00'
      ) AS TIMESTAMP) 
   + INTERVAL SUBSTRING(COL,11,2) second
FROM TEST;
```

We convert the input to ISO and then format the result to requested format.

```
Input:  YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS
Output: DDMMYYYYHHMISS
```

```
SELECT CAST(
   CONCAT( 
      SUBSTRING(COL,5,4),'-',
      SUBSTRING(COL,1,2),'-',
      SUBSTRING(COL,3,2),' ',
      SUBSTRING(COL,9,2),':',
      SUBSTRING(COL,11,2),':00'
      ) AS TIMESTAMP) 
   + INTERVAL SUBSTRING(COL,11,2) 
   FORMAT 'DDMMYYYYHHMISS' 
   AS corrected_date
FROM TEST;
```

Comment: Where is the conversion from the nonstandard string format to datetime? And the question is tagged Teradata, which does not have DATEADD.

Comment: @Fred Thank you for your comment- I do not have teradata and am working with the SQL I have. I have modified the query